# Can a REST Resource contain multiple objects?

Tags: rest, nested, resources

Is it against convention to return a REST resource object containing different but related objects ? Like :

a BankAccountResource containing :
  AccountInformation Object ( containing acct#,current Balance )
  List ( name & address )

Should this be broken into multiple resources ?  Like :

BankAccountResource containing just AccountInformation object &
AccountOwnerResource containing just AccountOwner Objects ?

Thanks,

-Sreeni

Comment: It breaks the design pattern I think. You can write a wrapper object to implement GET but what about the other verbs? Some [REST best practices](https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/)

Comment: Haven't thought thru that far. We are at the very early stages.. Thanks. I will read thru that link.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it against convention to return a REST resource object containing different but related objects ?

No.

Evidence: look at the web page you are reading this on right now.  It has your question, my answer, a summary of your reputation score, a list of meta data posts, some job listings, maybe some advertisements....